# Kotlin - Date Picker Dialog - How to show Previously selected date in Date Picker Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I have two textviews to set dates on it from DatePicker dialog in Android.

I have done the validation for the startDate(From Date) and endDate(To Date) as below :

```
 /**
 * Dialog for selecting custom date.
 * */
private fun openDatePickerDialog(view: TextView, dateType: String) {
    activity?.let { KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(it) }
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val dialog = DatePickerDialog(activity, { _, year, month, day_of_month ->
        calendar[Calendar.YEAR] = year
        calendar[Calendar.MONTH] = month
        calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = day_of_month
        Log.e(">>>>>>>>>> ", ">>>>>>>>>> else")

        val myFormat = OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
        view.text = sdf.format(calendar.time).toString()
        when (dateType) {
            "from" -> {
                filterDateFrom = view.text.toString()
            }
            "to" -> {
                filterDateTo = view.text.toString()
            }
        }
    }, calendar[Calendar.YEAR], calendar[Calendar.MONTH], calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH])

    if (view.id == R.id.tvDateTo && filterDateFrom.isNotEmpty() && filterDateFrom.contains("-")) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat)
        try {
            val mDate = sdf.parse(filterDateFrom)
            dialog.datePicker.minDate = mDate.time
            dialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else if (view.id == R.id.tvDateFrom && filterDateTo.isNotEmpty() && filterDateTo.contains("-")) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat)
        try {
            val mDate = sdf.parse(filterDateTo)
            dialog.datePicker.maxDate = mDate.time
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        //by default max date
        dialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```

And now I want to open this dialog with the last date set on specific textview,
i.e. If 24-05-2021 is set on textView, datePicker dialog should open with the same date selected.

Where I need to change to achieve this thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to creating DatePickerDialog is correct. You're using [**this**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int)) constructor to pre-select your date once date picker is open but your calendar instance is wrong.

You're using `val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()` which basically indicates current timestamp. In order to show selected time, you'll need manipulate calendar instance to set date first before passing it to date picker dialog.

Following would be the correct code snippet:

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar[Calendar.YEAR] = year // set your year to pre-select it on dialog
calendar[Calendar.MONTH] = month // set your month to pre-select it on dialog
calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = day_of_month // set your day to pre-select it on dialog
val dialog = DatePickerDialog(
        activity,
        { _, year, month, day_of_month -> },
        calendar[Calendar.YEAR], // Using the same calendar instance here as above will do the trick
        calendar[Calendar.MONTH],
        calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update DatePicker's date by using [updateDate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker#updateDate(int,%20int,%20int)) method.

Simply change your code like below

```
if (view.id == R.id.tvDateTo && filterDateFrom.isNotEmpty() && filterDateFrom.contains("-")) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat)
        try {
            val mDate = sdf.parse(filterDateFrom)
            dialog.datePicker.minDate = mDate.time
            dialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
            //New Code
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.time = mDate
            dialog.datePicker.updateDate(calendar[Calendar.YEAR], 
                calendar[Calendar.MONTH], calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH])

        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else if (view.id == R.id.tvDateFrom && filterDateTo.isNotEmpty() && filterDateTo.contains("-")) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat)
        try {
            val mDate = sdf.parse(filterDateTo)
            dialog.datePicker.maxDate = mDate.time
            //New Code
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.time = mDate
            dialog.datePicker.updateDate(calendar[Calendar.YEAR], 
                calendar[Calendar.MONTH], calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH])
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are always recreating the openDatePickerDialog hence new instances of the dialogs are created. The current instance does not have the data which is given to the previous dialog instance. So either you can make the date picker dialog as single instance or you could store the selected date in a global variable.

If you want to achieve without making modifications to the current dialog. You will need to store the date data in a global variable so instead of storing the date data from the date set listener like this

```
        calendar[Calendar.YEAR] = year
        calendar[Calendar.MONTH] = month
        calendar[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = day_of_month
```

You could create 3 global variables `day,month,year` and store the data from the date set listener like this

```
        this.year = year
        this.month = month
        this.day = day_of_month
```

and use the newly created variables as the date data when creating the dialog to show the data previous date data in date picker dialog.

Hence the final code will look like this

```
 var day = -1
 var year = -1
 var month = -1

 private fun openDatePickerDialog(view: TextView, dateType: String) {
    activity?.let { KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(it) }
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    if (day==-1 && month==-1 && year == -1) {
            year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        }    

    val dialog = DatePickerDialog(activity, { _, year, month, day_of_month ->
        this.year = year
        this.month = month
        this.day = day_of_month
        Log.e(">>>>>>>>>> ", ">>>>>>>>>> else")

        val myFormat = OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
        view.text = sdf.format(calendar.time).toString()
        when (dateType) {
            "from" -> {
                filterDateFrom = view.text.toString()
            }
            "to" -> {
                filterDateTo = view.text.toString()
            }
        }
    }, year, month, day)

    if (view.id == R.id.tvDateTo && filterDateFrom.isNotEmpty() && filterDateFrom.contains("-")) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat)
        try {
            val mDate = sdf.parse(filterDateFrom)
            dialog.datePicker.minDate = mDate.time
            dialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else if (view.id == R.id.tvDateFrom && filterDateTo.isNotEmpty() && filterDateTo.contains("-")) {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(OverAllAppDateDisplayFormat)
        try {
            val mDate = sdf.parse(filterDateTo)
            dialog.datePicker.maxDate = mDate.time
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        //by default max date
        dialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
    }
    dialog.show()
}
```